# Apache Rewrite without Redirect (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to do a simple rewrite without a redirect and apparently this is a hard task, for me anyways.

**Produces 404**

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ mysearch/result/?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

**Works, but not the way I need it to. Need it to work without redirect**

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ mysearch/result/?q=$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Anyone able to school me on this?  We are running php FPM (fast CGI) so not sure if that makes an impact.

Comment: Are `search` or `mysearch` real directories? Are there more rules in it?

Comment: The first is with [NC] (nocase), the second with [NE] (noescape). What link do you use for testing ? With special characters or cases ?